# Сквозной 443 порт ngnix

Tags: nginx, windows-10, ssl, https, virtualbox

Не могу настроить nginx (1.17.0), что бы был сквозной, без сертификата.

```
server {
        listen       442;
        server_name mysite.ru;
        location / {
            proxy_pass              https://sss.ru:8443;
        }

    }
    
    server {
        listen       443;
        server_name mysite.ru;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass              https://sss.ru:8443;
        }

    }
```

То есть сам веб-сервер находится в виртуалке по адресу https://sss.ru:8443. И нормально открывается в браузере. Nginx в основной машине. Для теста пробовал 442 сделать, сквозняк получается без проблем (Хотя нарушается дизайн, наверное из-за того, что до нжинкс приходит https, а уходит в браузер http). А вот с listen 443 ни как не получается.

Comment: Если нужен сквозной https, то вместо http нужно использовать tcp (не знаю, есть ли такая фича в nginx)

Comment: @andreymal есть, начиная с 1.9.0, по умолчанию не вкомпилирована.

Comment: и что делать? Я не могу запустить без рута 443 (стандартный запрет вплоть до 1024 порта) порт. А на судо нет доступа.

Comment: Вы успешно воззвали к Капитану! Его ответ: возьмите машину с рутом.